# Muss/soll so geschrieben werden

Tags: colloquial

Welches Verb ist hier zu benutzen?

> Jetzt, nach der Reform, muss/soll das Wort *Brennnessel* mit drei ***N*** geschrieben werden.

Comment: Es kommt auf den Kontext und die gewünschte Bedeutung an. Beides ist richtig und die Frage damit hier in dieser Form nicht beantwortbar.

Comment: "Jetzt **wird** das Wort mit drei N **geschrieben**." :)  Wenn man sagt "soll", dann signalisiert das: Man gibt hier wieder, was die Regel sagt. Das klingt auch ganz glatt. Man distanziert sich dann aber ein bisschen von der Regel, so als ob man selbst anders schreiben möchte...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das hängt vom Kontext ab. Wenn du Schüler oder Beamter bist, und einen Text in dieser Funktion (also als Schüler oder Beamter) schreibst, dann ist *»muss«* die richtige Wahl. Wenn du weder Schüler noch Beamter bist, oder wenn du zwar Schüler oder Beamter bist, aber einen Text in deiner Freizeit schreibst, dann ist *»soll«* richtig.

Das liegt daran, dass die vom Rechtschreibrat vorgegebene Rechtschreibung für die meisten Menschen nur eine Empfehlung ist.

Drei Beispiele:

1. Wenn ein Wirt in seinem Gasthaus einen Brennnesselsalat anbietet, aber *»Brennesselsalat«* in die Speisekarte schreibt, muss der Wirt dafür keine Strafe zahlen, und hat auch sonst keinerlei Konsequenzen zu befürchten.
2. Wenn ein Schüler einen Aufsatz über krautige Pflanzen im Garten schreibt, und darin die Brennnessel mit nur zwei N schreibt, wird seine Arbeit schlechter bewertet.
3. Wenn ein Beamter einen Bescheid ausstellt, in dem die Entfernung von Brennnesseln auf der Wiese des örtlichen Kindergartens verlangt wird, und er darin das Wort falsch schreibt, wird zwar der Bescheid deswegen nicht gleich ungültig, aber der Beamte kann von seinem Vorgesetzten deswegen gerügt werden. Wenn sich der Beamte beharrlich weigert, das Wort richtig zu schreiben, kann das im Extremfall sogar zu einem Disziplinarverfahren führen.

Darüber hinaus können Arbeitgeber ihre Mitarbeiter durch eine entsprechende Klausel im Dienstvertrag ebenfalls zur Einhaltung von Rechtschreibregeln verpflichten. Das ist vor allem bei Verlagen und Zeitungsredaktionen üblich. Allerdings können diese Verlage Regeln festlegen, die von den Regeln des Rechtschreibrates abweichen. Das war nach der Rechtschreibreform von 1996 sogar bei recht vielen Verlagen so der Fall. In vielen deutschen Verlagen war es den Redakteuren auch mehrere Jahre nach der Rechtschreibreform von 1996 (nämlich bis 2006) verboten, die Brennnessel mit drei N zu schreiben.

---

Davon abgesehen ist natürlich auch wichtig zu wissen, was die Modalverben bedeuten:

- **müssen**

  > Alle Schüler **müssen** das Wort *»Brennnessel«* mit drei N schreiben.

  Das bedeutet, dass die Schüler verpflichtet sind, das zu tun. Sie haben keine Wahl. Wenn sie dieser Pflicht nicht nachkommen, hat das Konsequenzen für sie.
- **sollen**

  > Alle Wirte **sollen** das Wort *»Brennnessel«* mit drei N schreiben.

  Das bedeutet, dass den Wirten empfohlen wird, das Wort auf diese Weise zu schreiben. Wenn sie dieser Empfehlung nicht Folge leisten, hat das keinerlei Konsequenzen für sie, aber trotzdem ist diese Schreibweise ein Verhalten, das man von Wirten erhofft.

Es gibt noch andere Modalverben (dürfen, wollen, mögen, können). Hier auf German.stackexchange gibt es bereits viele Fragen und Antworten, die sich damit beschäftigen.

Comment: Das Wort *schreiben* sollte mit *ei* geschrieben werden, nicht mit *ie*.

Comment: @Olafant: Danke für deinen Hinweis, aber du hast ausreichend Reputation, um meine Antwort zu editieren und den Fehler auszubessern.